# How to use Promise.all with Request in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'd like to do something along the lines of:

```
Promise.all([
    fetch(url1).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
    fetch(url2).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
    fetch(url3).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
    fetch(url4).then(function(response){ return response.json() })
]).then(allResponses => {    
    var data1 = allResponses[0];
    var data2 = allResponses[1];
    var data3 = allResponses[2];
    var data4 = allResponses[3];

    // process data....
});
```

The above is React.js code, I'd like to do the same thing but with Node.js on the server. Problem is I don't have fetch, I have request (should I even be using Request?). https://github.com/request/request
It's used in this way...

```
var request = require('request');

request(url1, function (error, response, body) {
});
```

But how would I use request with Promise.all? Because I want to fetch multiple things and only process them when all are done but in Node, and I'd rather not use a bunch of callbacks.

Comment: you can always install fetch on node too.

Comment: Have you tried looking into request-promise?  It makes it so requests are promises. `npm install request-promise` then add `var request = require('request-promise');`

Answer (score 4):

More concisely, after installing node-fetch, you can make a promise-returning fetch that resolves to json...

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
function fetchJSON(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}
```

...build an array of promises from an array of urls...

```
let urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4];
let promises = urls.map(url => fetchJSON(url));
```

...do something when those promises resolve...

```
Promise.all(promises).then(responses => console.log(responses));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the requests into promises:

```
function promiseRequest(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
      resolve(body);
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can do something like

```
const allBodies = await Promise.all([
  promiseRequest(url1),
  promiseRequest(url2),
  promiseRequest(url3)
]);
```

But it would be nicer to use `fetch` natively.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing and then I remembered about request-promise

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
npm install node-fetch
```

and then

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

and then I could use my code above:

```
Promise.all([
    fetch(url1).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
    fetch(url2).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
    fetch(url3).then(function(response){ return response.json() }),
    fetch(url4).then(function(response){ return response.json() })
]).then(allResponses => {
    var data1 = allResponses[0];
    var data2 = allResponses[1];
    var data3 = allResponses[2];
    var data4 = allResponses[3];

    // process data....
});
```