# How can I call a function only once all requests have finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

I am currently generating a few requests using the npm package `request` like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var options = {
        url: '...',
        headers: {
            '...'
        }
    };
    function callback(error, response, body) {

    };
    request(options, callback);

}


function toBeCalledWhenAllRequestsHaveFinished() {

}
```

I just don't know how to call `toBeCalledWhenAllRequestsHaveFinished()` only once all requests have finished.

What should be done ?

Comment: Alternate - use `Promise.all`. It gives success when all of your requests have completed

Comment: Have a look at https://davidwalsh.name/promises, it's from 2015 but still a pretty good source to understand promises

Comment: Using this `request` interface module, following this [`GitHub`](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) package.

[Reference to the original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580193/how-to-use-promise-all-with-request-in-node-js)

---

Install `node-fetch` using `npm install node-fetch --save`.

> Make a promise-returning fetch that resolves to JSON

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
function fetchJSON(url) {
    // Add options
    var options = {
        headers: {
            '...'
        }
    };
    return fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json());
}
```

> Build an array of promises from an array of URLs

```
let urls = [url1, url2, url3, url4];
let promises = urls.map(url => fetchJSON(url));
```

Call `toBeCalledWhenAllRequestsHaveFinished()` when all promises are resolved.

```
Promise.all(promises).then(responses => toBeCalledWhenAllRequestsHaveFinished(responses));
```

Comment: If you have to duplicate a whole answer, then you should rather close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The answer in the post was not marked as `Best Answer`, so until then, there is no point flagging this.

Comment: That doesn't matter. It is the most upvoted question at least.

Comment: It is, if you want to flag this post, I will not stop you.

Comment: What about the options ?

Comment: @TheProgrammer check the updated code. You should read documentation too.

Comment: @TheProgrammer also go to `node-fetch` npm webiste, `Ctrl`+`F` and search for `fetch(url[, options])`.

Comment: @Alex I am getting `{"size":0,"timeout":0}` as a response

Comment: I'm pretty sure the options need to be wrapped somehow, I've never used `node-fetch`, check the documentation and try follow what it says.

Comment: @Alex I can't accept an incomplete answer per SO rules

Comment: I presume you need to wrap your options in `{}` such as ` return fetch(url, {options})`

Comment: @TheProgrammer I'm not focused on the `Accepted Answer`, I'm focused on getting your code to work.

Comment: @TheProgrammer search for `// post with JSON` on [`bitinn/node-fetch github`](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch). It shows you how to add headers and other options.

Comment: @Alex If I do that, the response works, but I need to be able to modfiy the data that is sent back in each response, I am currently trying: }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("RESPONSE: "+JSON.stringify(response)); but it fails

Comment: @Alex Edited question.

Comment: @TheProgrammer have you added `responses` argument in your `toBeCalledWhenAllRequestsHaveFinished()` function. Add it and inside that function do `console.log(responses)`

Comment: @Alex Edited my question with full pseudocode now so you get a better picture of what I want to do. (Still got the same response after adding what you suggested)

Comment: @str Would you know what is happening here ?

Comment: Ultimately found the solution. You pointed me in the right direction. Answer accepted and upvoted :D Have a great day !

Comment: That's great to hear. Happy to be any help! :) @TheProgrammer